# mongoDB UPDATE - Workaround in Positional $ Operator issue

Tags: php, mongodb, positional-operator

I've been searching for quite some time about updating a nested array in mongoDB. So far, I know that there's an issue on positional $ operator on deep array, see this : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

But is there anyone in here who could help me create a workaround for this? 
This is my sample schema :

```
{
    folder_data : [
        {
            "folderName" : "First",
            "otherFolder" : []
        },
        {
            "folderName" : "Second",
            "otherFolder" : [
                {
                    "folderName" : "SecondA",
                    "otherFolder" : [
                        {
                            "folderName" : "SecondB",
                            "otherFolder" : [

                                // put my new data here                             

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "folderName" : "SecondBextra",
                            "otherFolder" : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "folderName" : "SecondAextra",
                    "otherFolder" : []
                },
            ]
        }
    ]   
}
```

and this is so far i've done :

Working (for first array) :

```
$collection->update(
            array('folder_data.folderName' => 'Second'), 
            array('$set' => array('folder_data.$.otherFolder' => array('test' => 'sample')))
        );
```

Not working :

```
$collection->update(
            array(
                'folder_data.folderName' => 'Second',
                'folder_data.otherFolder.folderName' => 'SecondA',
                'folder_data.otherFolder.otherFolder.folderName' => 'SecondB'
            ), 
            array('$set' => array('folder_data.$.otherFolder.$.otherFolder.$.otherFolder' => array('test' => 'sample'))));
```

Comment: You can't use multiple `$`'s. You would need to give explicit indices like `folder_data.2` for every level except one. The way to work around using deeply nested `$`'s is to redesign the schema - it's usually overall a better design that comes from doing this. If you edit the question to describe your use case (common queries), we can help you find a workaround with a different document design. You can also always retrieve the document, make the changes, and then insert the altered document on top of the original document.

Comment: Thanks wdberkeley, i'll try your suggestion and back here if i stuck in something again... but how about the my first parameter in "Not working" code? is it correct? 'cause i want to have more than 1 condition, like in mySql WHERE clause you can have more than 1 condition. So far, i couldn't find anything that has 2 or more conditions.

Comment: Multiple conditions on different fields can just be separated by commas - the default is to AND them together. The query condition looks fine for "not working".